# How can I remove a field from an embed by editing it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So let's say I create an embed and sent it to a channel. Here's the embed:

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(color)
        .setTitle(`${message.author.tag} wants to play.`)
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
        .setDescription(game)
        .setThumbnail(icon)
        .addField(`\u200b\n**React with ${emoji} to join.**`, "Remove your reaction to leave.");
```

Once it's sent, I want to edit that embed's title and description **and** delete the field I added at the end.

Here's the new embed I'm trying to create:

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed(reaction.message.embeds[0])
            .setTitle("This game has ended.")
            .setDescription("You can no longer join.");
```

This changes the title and description but I'm unsure on how to remove the field that I added too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is 6 months old, but in case anyone else stumbles here like I did you should not set embed.fields to null.  This prevents new fields from being added later using the addField method.  Instead set it to an empty array.

```
embed.fields = [];
```

Comment: Made this the solution, wish I knew this 6 months ago :(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I misunderstood. You can manually set the properties, like `embed.fields,` of the new embed object to null. [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=fields) is the documentation for the properties of RichEmbed.

In your specific case, to remove **all the fields** you might do:

```
embed.fields = null;
```

Comment: Oh sorry for not specifying that I need to keep the author, color, and thumbnail the same so I have to create an embed from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in v14:

```
embed.data.fields = [];
```

or

```
embed.data.fields = null;
```