# How do I edit embed and add new fields?

Tags: discord, discord.js

There is an Embed in which fields will be added and information will change, depending on the reactions.
How do I make changes to embed and add and remove fields?

If I try to edit via edit, it changes the entire message and inserts only the modified message

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle(`${day.format("DD.MM.YY, в (HH:mm)")}`)
    .setAuthor('Destiny 2', 'https://www.neira.app/img/Destiny2.png', 'https://www.bungie.net/')
    .setDescription(`**Заметка от лидера:** ${c.join(' ')}`)
    .setThumbnail(image_raid)
    .addField('Информация', `- Лидер группы: **#1** ${message.author}\n- Нажмите на реакцию`)
    .setFooter(`ID: ${message.id}`)

let jsonStr = messageReaction.message.embeds[0];
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));

obj['fields'].push(
{
    "value": "4",
    "name":"pending",
    "inline":false
});
jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);

messageReaction.message.edit("@here", { embed: jsonStr });
```

Comment: We need the code when a reaction is added

Comment: add code__________

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use, in your add reaction code:

```js
const newEmbed = messageReaction.message.embeds[0];
newEmbed.addField('pending', 4, false);
messageReaction.message.edit("@here", {
    embed: oldEmbed
});
```

Comment: how do I edit or delete a specific field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974403/how-can-i-remove-a-field-from-an-embed-by-editing-it

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `#addField()` method. To add new fields externally, simply do `<embedName>.addField()`

Here is an example of how embeds work:

```js
// at the top of your file
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Comment: where you defined the embed - 

`const joinEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()`

`joinEmbed` is the name

Comment: Add Reaction - new file

Comment: @Dragwor you have not defined the embed, and so you cannot treat it as if you have, please look at my post in greater detail - or add more detail and context to your own code